# How to display the values of an objects associative model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(I hope I used the correct terminology in the title apologies if not)

My 'profile' model has a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relationship with my 'place' model.

On the 'profile' index page I want to list and display the 'places' of a 'profile' but I can only get to display what seems like the memory address of the profile.places

My index view:

```
<% @profile.each do |p| %>
  <P><%= p.id %>: <%= p.bio %> Postcodes: <%= p.places %></p>
<% end%>
```

Displayed on screen:

3: I'm drinking some tea hun Postcodes: #Place::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ffe61c2fd28>

---

I have tried some kind of loop but I'm just getting in to a mess.
How can I display the items of the places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to **establish the connection**(add `to_a` or `all` after association name).

Second, you need to do something with the places, if you want them as string. for example

```
p.places.map(&:postcode).join(', ')
```

Comment: Thanks guys. They both answered the question so I guess its etiquette to give the green tick to the first?   TheShalit- what do you mean by establish the connection?

Comment: When you are using association method you are getting `CollectionProxy` and not an `Array`, if you want an array use `to_a` or `all`

Answer (score 1):

`p.places` is a collection of place objects.  When you put something in erb tags then Rails calls `.to_s` on it, to turn it into a string, and that's what you're seeing there: the result of viewing a collection as a string.

What you need to do is extract the **information** out of the objects in the collection, and structure some html around it.  Something like this:

```
<% p.places.each do |place| %>
  <div><%= place.name %></div>
<% end %>
```